# How do you remove the "Your Main Benefit Statement Goes Here." From one of my pages?

Tags: theme-development

I'm working in a site for my employer and he wants me to fix a piece of the website I have no idea how to alter, and help?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a theme option somewhere in your theme.  Go to your admin and look around for options related to your theme.  Maybe check Appearance > Customize or an options menu with your theme name.

Comment: Googling that text, I've found it in more than one theme (Pressive, Rise so far) so I'd guess it's from a standard database template. In both cases though it's on a page called 'Sales Page' or 'Sales Page Template'. Do you have a page called either of those?

Comment: Yes I am using the Pressive theme and nowhere can I find something that will allow me to change it in the customize option menu. And Rup, no I don't have a page called either of those.

Comment: If you still can't find it, I suggest you work out if it's coming from a template file or from your database. Grep your theme files for some of the words. Take a fresh database backup and grep that for the phrase too. Hopefully then you'll discover if it's in your database, which table and which field.